# Handling shutdown signal in spring

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-rabbit

I have a spring application that uses camel for setting up a route to consume from a queue.
I use rabbitmq as the message broker.
Now the problem is that if the rabbitmq broker falls the connection is not autmatically recovered.
I tried enabling automaticRecoveryEnabled. But I get noSuchMethodError.
I'll show the code used to create connection.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:data/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.properties"/>
        <route>
            <from uri="rabbitmq://{{mete.rabbitmq.host}}:{{mete.rabbitmq.port}}/{{mete.rabbitmq.exchange}}
            ?queue={{mete.rabbitmq.queue}}&amp;username={{mete.rabbitmq.username}}
            &amp;password={{mete.rabbitmq.password}}&amp;exchangeType={{mee.rabbitmq.exchange.type}}
            &amp;queueArgsConfigurer=#myArgs&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;automaticRecoveryEnabled=true&amp;networkRecoveryInterval=654&amp;requestedHeartbeat=987"/>
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
            <process ref="myProcessor"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Below is the stack  trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(Z)V
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.getOrCreateConnectionFactory(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:278)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.connect(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:195)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.openConnection(RabbitMQConsumer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.doStart(RabbitMQConsumer.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2869)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3163)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3099)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3029)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2797)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2653)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2467)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2486)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2432)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:255)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:332)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at rabbitmqClient.AbstractConsumer.openAMQPConnection(AbstractConsumer.java:77)
    at rabbitmqClient.ConsumerPoolExecutor.startConsumer(ConsumerPoolExecutor.java:122)
    at medagate.MedagateContext.main(MedagateContext.java:15)
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by `shutdown signal`

Comment: I'll edit the question to understand the error.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? And can you paste the stacktrace error you get.

Comment: I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ client JARs are you using? Seems like it does not support that option.

Comment: Rectified it by changing version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurred because of the amqp-client dependency.
When the version is changed from 2.8.4 to 3.5.1 the code works fine.
New dependency is :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```